# How to return only numerical values, in ascending order

Tags: mysql

**How to get record in ascending order**

My data is

```
101    
102    
w    
200    
11        
NO        
131        
2        
XYZ
```

And I only want to return numbers, in ascending order.
Datatype is `varchar`

I want to write query as :

```
SELECT rno FROM  ml_entry 
WHERE (rno NOT LIKE '%[a-z]%') 
ORDER BY rno
```

The above SQL creates the below output:

```
101
102
11
131
154
2
```

But this is the output I want:

```
2
11
101
102
131
154
```

Any advice?

Comment: convert the column to numeric when you select it.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I cleared that comment and made a new one.  Which someone now has provided that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should do something like this:

```
SELECT rno, convert(rno, UNSIGNED INTEGER) as num 
FROM ml_entry WHERE (rno NOT LIKE '%[a-z]%') ORDER BY num ASC
```

Since `rno` is a varchar, your ordering will be lexical. You need to convert the varchar to integer and then order by it.

Here is a [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ee110/1).